# Flutter title doesn't change

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the title but despite the fact I changed the title it still shows the previous title on the tab of the browser.

```
 void main() {
  runApp(Myapp());
}


class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'New title ',  : but still shows the old title on the browser
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          home: NavScreen(),
        );
      }
```

}

Comment: Where do you expect this title to show up? And what does the starting point of your code look like (the class you're calling from runApp() )?

Comment: Yes, I've been coding for a while, know ins and outs. run Flutter clean but still, the previous title showed up on the tab of browser.

Comment: When you saw browser, do you mean this is a flutter web app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the title during the run time, you just need to wrap it with the stateful Widget.

If your App title is static and does not change after a build, try clearing the flutter cache and rebuild your application again.